# What's wrong with this D-to-C linkage?

Tags: c, linker, d

I've set up a trivial test to link D code with C, but I'm running into linker problems.

```
// Compiled with "gcc -c CTest.c."

void SayHello()
{
    printf("%s", "Hello, world!");
}
```

```
// Compiled with "dmd DTest.d CTest.o."

extern (C) void SayHello();

void main()
{
    SayHello();
}
```

`ld` spits out:

```
ld: warning: in CTest.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols:
  "_SayHello", referenced from:
    __Dmain in DTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

I've tried manually specifying `CTest.c`'s architecture with `-m32 -march=i386`, but that gives me a bus error at runtime.  I've never gotten a bus error before, so that just goes right over my head.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: well.. unsuported file format.. not to be captain obvious here, but try compiling with D fronted for gcc (gdc i think)

Comment: @fazo Why would that be necessary?  The D website [says it can be done](http://www.d-programming-language.org/interfaceToC.html) without much additional effort.

Comment: it's not about c<->c++ interface but interoperability between D and c/c++ objects produced with incompatible compilers.

Comment: FWIW, doing exactly as you have done on OSX 10.6.8, gcc 4.2.1, dmd 2.055 works fine for me.

Comment: @PeterAlexander That's very odd; I'm using the exact same versions as you are!  Why would that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have the 32bit dmd installed. Your initial attempt to change gcc seems correct, maybe try dropping the -march option. Otherwise try the D compilation with -m64 then try -m32 if it didn't work.

Yes dmd can link with GCC generated object files targeted at the Linux ELF format, and I believe MacOS/BSD? March format. Windows DMD produces OMF while COFF is more popular now.

Comment: Dropping `-march` did the trick!  Do I dare ask why that worked?

Comment: Here is a lot more information than you ever wanted to know regarding linking D to C.  The main thing that bit me was Thread Local Storage. Hope you find something useful. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7774365/978992

Comment: I am unsure what -march is supposed to do (optimization?) but I never used it myself.

Answer (score -3):

Digital Mars compilers and GCC compilers use different object file formats. Either use (gdc and gcc) or (dmd and dmc).

Comment: Can I work around this by putting it in a "formal" library, i.e. `libFoo.a`?

Comment: Not sure but I doubt it. But dynamically linked libraries (.dll, or .so) should probably work.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong again, dynamic libraries don't work, either.  Same error.

Comment: DMD only produces different formats on Windows. Archives are still the same format, shared I think just has additional requirements.